# HTML javascript form submitted when image input button

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit

I have a form that contains this single input field, which is nothing more than a button to Print the current web page:

```
<div align="center">
<input type="image" src="../Images/print.jpg" value="Print" onclick="printpage();" /></div>
</div>
```

After the printing, the page re-submits itself (to itself). Why does it do this and can I stop it?

If I just change the type to "input", this code does not re-submit itself after printing:

```
<div align="center">
<input type="input" src="../Images/print.jpg" value="Print" onclick="printpage();" /></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, our style conventions require me to use that button image rather than the standard input button.

Comment: If the image button has no functionality without Javascript, then write it with Javascript into the document.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `onclick` handler to `onclick="printpage(); return false;"` - that will prevent the button from doing anything besides running the JavaScript.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the *reason* you need to do this is that an input element of type "image" is by default a *submit* button, and therefore submits the form when clicked.

Answer (score 3):

add 'return false;' to your onClick event:

```
onclick="printpage();return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a

> return false;

at the end of your code
 therefor

```
<input type="input" src="../Images/print.jpg" value="Print" onclick="printpage();return false;" /></div>
```